# Angular unsubscribe from BehaviorSubject as Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I create a `BehaviorSubject` in one of my services, and using it asObservable to subscribe to it later, but i need to unsubscribe after the controller is destroyed, how can i unsubscribe from it.

**Services**

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

  private currentStepObject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  public currentStepObservable = this.currentStepObject.asObservable();

  constructor(
  ) { }

  public changecurrentStep(step: number): void {
    this.currentStepObject.next(step);
  }
```

**Controller**

```
 import { ReaderService } from '../../../../services/reader/reader.service';

   constructor(
    private readerServices: ReaderService
   ) { }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.initDocumentData();
     this.readerServices.currentStepObservable
      .subscribe((step) => {
        this.currentStep = step;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
  }
```

Comment: Here by the maintainer of RxJS: https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from \`Subscription\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try takeUntil with helpful inner Subject.

*UPDATE:* In this case you don't have to manually unsubscribe from each subscription in a component, because you may have a bit more than one inside.

```
import { ReaderService } from '../../../../services/reader/reader.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators'

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private unsubscribe$: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  constructor(
    private readerServices: ReaderService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initDocumentData();
    this.readerServices.currentStepObservable.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
    )
    .subscribe((step) => {
      this.currentStep = step;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Assign it to a `subscription` variable of type `Subscription` that can be `import`ed from `rxjs` and then `unsubscribe` from it in the `ngOnDestroy`

```
import { ReaderService } from '../../../../services/reader/reader.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

subscription: Subscription;

constructor(
  private readerServices: ReaderService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.initDocumentData();
  this.subscription = this.readerServices.currentStepObservable
    .subscribe(step => this.currentStep = step);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

### OR use `async` pipe in the template:

```
import { ReaderService } from '../../../../services/reader/reader.service';

currentStep$;

constructor(
  private readerServices: ReaderService
) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.initDocumentData();
  this.currentStep$ = this.readerServices.currentStepObservable;
}
```

And then in the template:

```
{{ this.currentStep$ | async }}
```

This way, you won't have to take care of `unsubscribe`ing from the `Observable` and Angular will take care of it.

Answer (score 1):

Each Observable.subscribe() returns a subscription. It would be better to create a subscriptions array and add all the subscriptions in it.
On destroy of component(ngOnDestroy lifecycle hook), loop through the subscriptions array and call unsubscribe on it.

Doing this you need not to manage different subscription from different subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 import { ReaderService } from '../../../../services/reader/reader.service';
 subscription : Subscription;

 constructor(
 private readerServices: ReaderService
   ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
 this.initDocumentData();
 this.subscription = this.readerServices.currentStepObservable
  .subscribe((step) => {
    this.currentStep = step;
  });
   }

 ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
 }
```